# Socket.io and a memory leak in internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-9, socket.io

I'm writing an application using socket.io to emit data to connected browsers and have found a problem with IE9 specifically. IE8 handles this very well, IE 10 and other browsers also manage this well with the except of firefox which does it's garbage clean but allows memory to grow quite a bit before getting to it.  But with IE 9 memory grows and grows until the system is out of memory.  My test case is pretty basic and is as follows:

Node app with socket.io runs the following code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('test', 'Hello I am a memory leak in IE9');  
},10);
```

Client side code is as follows:

```
socket.on('test', function(data) {
    data = null;
});
```

Running at the 10ms interval is just to show this dramatically, another way would be to send a very large string. Either way, only in IE9 does this leak. I've tested with IE8 and IE9 both on the socket.io flashsocket and using long polling, IE9 has leak in both instances, IE8 does not.

I know someone will respond with something about not using IE < 10, unfortunately that is a requirement of the project.

My question is, is this a problem with Socket.io somehow, or is it an issue with IE9?  Is there something I can do in my code to mitigate this memory leak or to initialize better GC?

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug? Is there a link to the bug report?

Comment: I had a thread in the socket.io google group going, the general consensus has been that the real issue at hand is IE9's handling of various memory objects (or lack thereof).